# Take last 30 mins Entries in Linux Log File

Tags: linux, bash

Could you please guide how i can get the entries of last 30mins from a log file. i have tried the below but not working.

```
sed '/$(date -d "-30 minutes" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')/,/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')/! d' Time_Taken_log.log
```

PFB the sample of entries in my log file

```
2019-03-07 15:32:01.425: 1012
2019-03-07 15:32:01.456: 886
2019-03-07 15:32:01.484: 729
2019-03-07 15:32:01.505: 747
2019-03-07 15:32:01.527: 716
2019-03-07 15:32:01.529: 919
2019-03-07 15:32:01.531: 917
2019-03-07 15:32:01.584: 964
2019-03-07 15:32:01.599: 791
2019-03-07 15:32:01.637: 836
```

Would really appreciate your help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better use `logstash` to process this log and push to `ElasticSearch` and then you can query as per your wish

Comment: I want this achieved through a bash script. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The format of your file is excellent for an easy comparison.

```
start=$(date -d "-30 minutes" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
awk -v s="$start" 's<$0' file.log
```

Comment: @brunorey, ...speaking as someone whose answer has grep compare every line from the beginning up to the first match, I'm not sure you have a ton of room to talk (unless we expect the bulk of the contents of the file to be in the 30-minute window).

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient for large files is to use `tac` to read from the end, and stop as soon as you see a date older than your goal:

```
awk -F: -v stop_when_before="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d '-30 minutes')" '
  $1 < stop_when_before { exit }
  1 { print }
' < <(tac Time_Taken_log.log)
```

There's no reason to read the first 19.95GB of your 20GB file if you only care about the 50MB most recent content.

If you want the contents to be in their original order, pipe the output of `awk` back to `tac` (though I personally advise against that absent a compelling reason; `tac` is very cheap reading a seekable file where it can jump straight to the end, but reading from a pipe it has to buffer everything all the way to the end before any output can be generated).